# Combine Object base on object property in array on objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I just want to merge the objects on the base of one of the properties also want to add missing **Days name** in the output.

```
Take this for an example:

var array =  [
       {
      "heure1": "14:00",
      "heure2": "17:00",
      "day": "Sunday",
    },
       {
      "heure1": "08:00",
      "heure2": "13:00",
      "day": "Sunday",
    },
       {
      "heure1": "14:00",
      "heure2": "16:00",
      "day": "Monday",
    },
       {
      "heure1": "08:00",
      "heure2": "18:00",
      "day": "Monday",
    },
  ];
```

Expected result:

```
var array =  [
       {
      "heure": ["14:00","17:00","08:00","13:00"],
      "day": "Sunday",
    },
     {
      "heure": ["14:00","16:00","08:00","18:00"],
      "day": "Monday",
    },
    {
      "heure": [],
      "day": "Saturday",
    },
    {
      "heure": [],
      "day": "Friday",
    },
    {
      "heure": [],
      "day": "Thursday",
    },
    {
      "heure": [],
      "day": "Wednesday",
    },
    {
      "heure": [],
      "day": "Tuesday",
    },

  ];
```

Im also trying some of stack overflow answers but Not getting success :-(
Order of the day dose not matter.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share your attempt and where you are stuck.

Comment: BTW, that is a strange order of days in your desired output... What is the logic?

Comment: order of days does not matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My try

```
<script>
    var array = [{
            "heure1": "14:00",
            "heure2": "17:00",
            "DAY": "Sunday",
        },
        {
            "heure1": "08:00",
            "heure2": "13:00",
            "DAY": "Sunday",
        },
        {
            "heure1": "14:00",
            "heure2": "16:00",
            "DAY": "Monday",
        },
        {
            "heure1": "08:00",
            "heure2": "18:00",
            "DAY": "Monday",
        },
    ];
    var days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Sunday", "Saturday"];
    var result = [];
    days.map(function (day) {
        var daysInArray = array.filter(function (a) {
            return day == a.DAY
        })
        // console.log(daysInArray);
        if (daysInArray.length) {
            time = [];
            daysInArray.map(function (item, i) {
                for (var key in item) {
                    if (daysInArray[0].hasOwnProperty(key) && key != "DAY") {
                        time.push(item[key])
                    }
                }
            })
            result.push({
                "day": day,
                "heure": time
            })
        } else {
            result.push({
                "day": day,
                "heure": []
            })
        }
    })
    console.log(result);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is more dynamic then others and also very easy to understand.

Comment: @osamasomy this verifies the adage: why want to keep it simple when you can do it complicated ...

Answer (score 1):

You could first create the 7 entries for the 7 days of the week, each with an empty array for the `heure` property.

Then iterate the original data, look up the right entry, and push the two times to the `heure` array.

Note that your `Day` property has different spellings in your example input (DAY, Day). I would strongly suggest to use all lowercase for such property names.

Here is an implementation:

```js
var array =  [{"heure1": "14:00","heure2": "17:00","day": "Sunday",}, {"heure1": "08:00","heure2": "13:00","day": "Sunday",}, {"heure1": "14:00","heure2": "16:00","day": "Monday",}, {"heure1": "08:00","heure2": "18:00","day": "Monday", },];

let days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];
let obj = Object.fromEntries(days.map(day => [day, { heure: [], day }]));
for (let {heure1, heure2, day} of array) obj[day].heure.push(heure1, heure2);
let result = Object.values(obj);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: What about this answer? Does it suit your needs?

Comment: Yes this is very help full but one of the guy send me more dynamic answer. 
by the Thanks for fast response I really appreciate.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't see how that is more dynamic, but OK. Note it iterates the input several times, this solution only iterations the input once.

Comment: His answer not depend on the key values like **heure1** if some data is changed, I think it should work.

Comment: by the way I really appreciate your Answer as well.

Comment: Oh, but then if you have a property `nom` then this gets pushed into `heure` as well. I did not think that was your intention.

Answer (score 1):

my way...

```js
var arr_1 = 
    [ { heure1: '14:00', heure2: '17:00', day: 'Sunday' } 
    , { heure1: '08:00', heure2: '13:00', day: 'Sunday' } 
    , { heure1: '14:00', heure2: '16:00', day: 'Monday' } 
    , { heure1: '08:00', heure2: '18:00', day: 'Monday' } 
    ] 

const days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']

const res = days.map(d=>
        {
        let r = { heure:[], day:d }
        arr_1.filter(x=>x.day===d)
             .forEach(({heure1,heure2})=> { r.heure.push(heure1,heure2) })
        r.heure.sort() 
        return r
        })


console.log( res  )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that result structure necessary?

If not, modifying the result structure, you could do something like this:

```js
const getHeureByDay = (heureArray) => {
  let result = {
    Sunday: { heure: [] },
    Monday: { heure: [] },
    Tuesday: { heure: [] },
    Wednesday: { heure: [] },
    Thursday: { heure: [] },
    Friday: { heure: [] },
    Saturday: { heure: [] },
  };
  
  heureArray.forEach((heureItem) => {
    Object.keys(heureItem).forEach((key) => {
      if (key !== "day") {
        result[heureItem.day].heure.push(heureItem[key]);
      }
    })
  });
  
  return result;
};

const heureArray = [
  {
    "heure1": "14:00",
    "heure2": "17:00",
    "day": "Sunday",
  },
  {
    "heure1": "08:00",
    "heure2": "13:00",
    "day": "Sunday",
  },
     {
    "heure1": "14:00",
    "heure2": "16:00",
    "day": "Monday",
  },
     {
    "heure1": "08:00",
    "heure2": "18:00",
    "day": "Monday",
  }
];

console.log(getHeureByDay(heureArray));
```